# Dummy Base class in C++ for pseudo polymorphic std::container

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, containers, derived

I have a template class from which I create several instances during an
application.I want all those objects to be stored in one container,
preferable `std::vector`. I already searched the board and creating a
non template base-class,
from which the template class inherits, should do the trick, because then
I can create a `std::vector` with elements being pointers to the base-class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class base {};

template <typename T1>
class test_class : public base {
  T1 X;
};

int main() {
  vector<base*> vec;
  vec.push_back(new test_class<double>);
  vec.push_back(new test_class<int>);

  return 0;
}
```

It seems to be that easy, my question is: Is there anything wrong with
defining such a 'dummy' base class, just in order to be able to store
polymorphic derived classes in a container? Do I have to be aware of something?

Comment: I see nothing polymorphic about it. No virtuals = No polymorphism. All you have there is a common base. (static poly not withstanding, which this isn't). And I concur with a hopefully resurrected answer that you should be using smart pointers.

Comment: Yes it's that easy, but how do you want to work further with the stored contents? Using dynamic cast checks?

Comment: Could you post some more realistic code, e.g. how you plan to access the `X`? You can likely solve this without having to resort to inheritance and virtuals, http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil

Comment: The only thing I could warn you is the lack of a virtual dtor on the base class. If its not virtual, when cleaning the vector `delete` will not call the proper instance destructor, it will call the base class destructor.